# Is there a way to get a enveloped document with all custom fields populated on it, using Docusign Rest API?

Tags: docusignapi

I am working in a implementation using Docusign to e-sing some documents , I am able to create the envelope successfully  a,  but when I use the API  to get the document  in order to show to the user the document before to be signed  the document is  empty without the custom fields (tabs) that I have set in the template, so my question is : is there any way to get a document with all  custom fields populated even is the document had not been signed?

I have tried using the Docusign REST-APIS to  get the document:

**GET/v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents/{documentId}**
 That works  I am able to get the PDF file but I dont know why the custom fields  are not present in the document

Comment: You want to show someone (who is not the signer), the documents, with the tabs populated, before the envelope is sent for signature?

Comment: Yes @LarryK , That is exactly   that I   want to do, I need to show  the  document with all the tabs populated to a sales officer that  validates the document before  to send it to the signer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get PDF with the prepopulated tabs data and want to send for review to Sales Officer then you can achieve it by two ways:

- If envelope is created with sent status, then you can add Sales
  Officer as the first Recipient as Signer Type and add a Approve Tab
  for that signer, that way if Sales Officer approves then DocuSign
  will move to next recipient in the workflow and if Sales Officer
  declines then workflow will stop. So with this approach, everything
  is handled by DocuSign and you do not need to get PDF copy and then
  get approval via Email by sending PDF as an attachment, also approval
  or decline is captured in the audit trail and also in CoC.
- If envelope is created with draft status, then you can download the
  PDF with prepopulated tab data by using below API call,

  **https://{{EnvironmentVal}}/restapi/v2/accounts/{{AccountIdVal}}/envelopes/{{envelopeId}}/documents/{{documentId}}?show_changes=true**

to make any of the above solution work, you need to need to enable a Sending Setting under Admin at an Account Level which will show the Tab Value on the document for everyone.

[image]

Comment: I have tested  the second approach and It works perfectly , Thank you very much

Comment: @AndresVasquez Can you please accept the answer if it resolved your issue?

Answer (score 1):

There's an account-wide setting for this.

Navigate to Go to Admin > Sending Settings > *When an envelope is sent, write the initial value of the field for all recipients*.

As far as I know this can't be toggled at the envelope level by the API.